# Update Dojo filtering select position on partial refresh of XPage

Tags: dojo, xpages

In one of my XPages I got a radio button. If I choose value of the radio button, a partial refresh is called.

- Value 1 of the radio button only displays a new button in the same line
- Value 2 adds some more fields beneath the radio button group

Beneath this new fields there is a Dojo filtering select field to choose from a list of employees.

If I select value 1, the filtering select works fine.
If I select value 2, the filtering select still starts at the "old" position, without recognizing the space, the new fields need

[image]

How can I update the position of the filtering select list? The partial refresh is for the complete content of the page, but does not seem to work here.

Here is the code of the radio group, which does the partial refresh on change:

```
            <xp:radioGroup id="rbgSelectEducationType" layout="pageDirection" 
        value="#{docApplication.EducationType}">
            <xp:this.readonly>
    <![CDATA[#{javascript:docApplication.getItemValueString("ZwfStepName") != "Start"}]]></xp:this.readonly>
            <xp:selectItem itemLabel="ESG Veranstaltung aus dem Katalog" 
        itemValue="ESG-Veranstaltung">
            </xp:selectItem>
            <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Externe Veranstaltung" 
        itemValue="Externe-Veranstaltung">
            </xp:selectItem>
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" 
        refreshMode="partial" refreshId="wcEventDetails">
</xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:radioGroup>
```

And here is the code of the filtering select dropdown:

```
<xe:djFilteringSelect id="Approver" value="#{docApplication.Approver}" ignoreCase="true">
<xe:this.rendered><![CDATA[#javascript:docApplication.getItemValueString("ZwfStepName")=="Start"}]]></xe:this.rendered>
<xp:selectItems id="selectItems2">

<xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:if(docApplication.isEditable()){
        getComponent("AllUsersLastFirst").getValue().split("#");
    }}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:selectItems>
<xp:eventHandler event="onChange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="panelBody" id="eventHandler2">
<xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var dbPR = new Array(applicationScope.srv, applicationScope.pathPR);
    var Approver:com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.dojo.form.UIDojoFilteringSelect = getComponent("Approver");
    var lookup=@DbLookup(dbPR,applicationScope.xpPersonByLastNameFirstName,Approver.getValue(),2);
    lookup=@If(@IsError(lookup),"error",lookup);
    if (lookup=="error") {
        errormsg = valstrings.getString("ccEsgDocWflContentApprover.lookup1");
        globalScriptErrors.add(errormsg);
        requestScope.put("scriptErrors", globalScriptErrors);
    }   
        @SetField("NotesNameApprover", lookup);}]]></xp:this.action>
</xp:eventHandler>
</xe:djFilteringSelect>
```

Comment: Mi Matthias, could you please paste some of the related code? To be honest, I don't quite get what you're trying to achieve ;)

Comment: Ah, at second thought I think that now I've got what you mean: the selection box of the approver field shows at the wrong position, correct? - Are you using the ExtLib's version of filteringSelect, or the standard dojo one? And: do you see this effect only if you change you radio value in an open page, or also right after opening a new page?

Comment: It's the standard filtering select control and as far as I know, this effect only shows up in this case here with the partial refresh and not when opening a new page

Comment: This is weird indeed. Can you try the Extlib version just to see if it behaves the same way?

Comment: Hm, which element of the Extension Library do you mean? I can't find anything like this dropdown box

Comment: with the extlib installed and active you find it inside the "Dojo Form" control category

Comment: Curious question: if you resize the window after the partial refresh before using the box, does it still stay at the wrong place?

Comment: Yes, it's still at the wrong place

Comment: @Lothar: In this case I'm already using this control. I thought there would be another version in the Extension Library category.

Answer (score 1):

The filtering select is composed of a number of HTML elements (Firebug is your friend here). When you do a partial refresh that doesn't include the select itself, it isn't drawn again, thus the dropdown stays at the same position. The short answer: include the dropdown in the partial refresh.

Comment: But the filtering select is already part of the partial refresh - or do you mean I have to do a special refresh on that filtering select? I would need a multiple partial refresh then

Comment: maybe you could post the relevant portions of your xml code; as I mailed to you yesterday I gave this a quick check and for me it worked fine